# Make IntEnum members callable while keeping their comparison behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say the class Color is an enumeration:

```
from enum import IntEnum
class Color(IntEnum):
    red = 1
    blue = 2
    green = 3
```

Now, let's say I want to associate each of those member with a function AND keeping their value. i.e doing something like this

```
Colors.red()
```

Would call a function that I'd assign in someway.
And keeping the IntEnum behavior, meaning that

```
Colors.red == 1
```

Would still return `True`

I guess I need to define a new superclass for my enumeration, but how?

The only thing near that that I have managed to do is:

```
class Colors(Enum):
    red = (1, f)
    blue = (2, g)
    green = (3, h)
```

Where `f` `g` and `h` are functions.
However. With this method, the only way to access the value is

```
Colors.red.value[0]
```

And to call the function this is

```
Colors.red.value[1](args)
```

Wich is, in my opinion, pretty ugly, especially when names are a bit longs, when you have to call function a lot of times and with a lots of arguments

So is there a way to do what I want or do I need to stick to the uggly version?

Comment: This is really unintuitive behavior. Can you not just put put your functions in a dictionary and call them by doing `d[Colors.red]()`?

Comment: @Blender It's a good idea in deed. The only point on doing that is that forces you to re create a dictionnary, with each values. With big enums it'll take a lot of place. However the idea is really good and I'll think about it if there is no way to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: How big are your enums?

Comment: @ It could go from 12 to 20 items approximately. That's not that big, but that add 20 lines that could be avoided if there is a way to give the function at the same time as the value. Anyway I'm not complaining at all about your idea, it's really simple and effective!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with just calling `Color.red.value` on the enum in your first example?

Comment: Just realised these attributes where already there when I tried to compose an answer with metaclasses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Against my better judgement, I've decided to unravel the magic threads that hold `Enum`s together. Here's what I came up with:

```
from enum import Enum

class FuncEnum(Enum):
    def __init__(self, val, func=None):
        self.val = val
        self.func = func or lambda: None
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.val >= other
    # and etc... not sure how @total_ordering will work here!

class Color(FuncEnum):
    red = (1, lambda x: x**2)
    blue = (2, lambda x: x**3)
    green = (3, lambda x: x**4)

Color.red(4)  # 16
Color.red == 1  # True
Color.blue(2)  # 8
```

This also supports reassignment, so afterwards:

```
Color.red.func = str.lower
Color.red("LOWERCASE")  # "lowercase"
```

Comment: Hmm, that's not far from what I thought of, but I missed the imlicit "magic" of  Enums, so I fiddled with creating callable ints (or somewhat). That's where I gave up.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and plain, although a nightmare for readability and comprehensibility. Simply implements Python callable interface by providing a `__call__` method. Bury it in some module, implement `__all__` and never import anything besides `Color` class.

```
from enum import IntEnum
f1 = lambda x: x
f2 = lambda x: x*x
f3 = lambda x: x*x*x

class Color(IntEnum):
    red = 1
    blue = 2
    green = 3
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # alternatively some generic function of self.value
        return LUT[self](*args, **kwargs)


LUT = {Color.red: f1, Color.blue: f2, Color.green: f3}

assert Color.red(1) == 1
assert Color.blue(2) == 4
assert Color.green(3) == 27
assert Color.blue > Color.red
```

Edit:
Much better (more readable, less hacky etc.) would be to define explicit callable interface on Enum.

```
class Color(IntEnum):
    red = 1
    blue = 2
    green = 3
    def get_something(self, x):
        # e.g.
        return x ** self.value
```

Any users of this Enum would do something like:

```
o = Obj()
o.color.get_something(123)
```

With with proper name of `get_something` would be readable, easy to understand for pylint and other static analysis tools and less error-prone.

Comment: Wouldn't that require to create an instance of the class and call that instance, but neither the class itself, nor one of the class attributes? Hmm.. tried; and it seems to work, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Olaf could you clarify? Enum does some of metaclass magic beneath, this solution is also very hacky (because of requirement being hacky itself) and I cannot understand what do you mean. `Color` is not a class here, and `red`, `green`, `blue` are not class attributes. Please refer to [How are enums different?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#how-are-enums-different)

Comment: @Olaf Maybe becauses we are working with enums, where attributes are kind of instances. Anyway thanks, I'll try that. I'll let the thread open for some times to see other possibilities

Comment: I just wondered why the __call__ works on the class attributes (it certainly _is_ a class actually, as everything is a class) and not on an instance. However the reference to metaclass "magic" does explain it. I did not take this into account; just read a primer on them. There seems to be much more behind them than I actually thought. Fascinating!

Comment: Is is still possible to put the functions into the class definition as `@staticmethod` and use the class-dict to lookup them? e.g. using a unifirm naming scheme like `<color>_func` or similar? I think that would increase readability significantly (and keep everything in the class' namespace).

Comment: Enums work through sufficiently advanced technology as to be indistinguishable from magic. As a rule: I don't reverse engineer magic. All my condolences to @ŁukaszR. when his interpreter explodes from gazing into the void. Also great answer.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Well, I for myself actually _do_ want to know how the magic works. Unfortunately, I'm not Mr. Bond (I don't "have all the time in the world"). But I also appreciate it when someone does know it.

Comment: @Olaf agreed -- my comment's tongue was entirely in its cheek! :)

Comment: @AdamSmith: Another thing I want to know: what actually does that mean:"tongue was ...". Sorry, I'm not a native speaker, but really like to learn new phrases. Treying to picture this, but still not sure.

Comment: @Olaf Ha, I'm playing with words, sorry about that. To say a remark is "Tongue in cheek" is to say it's not entirely serious, so when I said my *comment's* tongue was in its cheek, I was just trying to say I don't at all discourage poking at "magic" constructions.

Comment: @AdamSmith: I knew it was, but not sure if I got it right, according to your explanation, I actually did. Thanks! :-)